# Lost Messages app by mistake

Tags: macos, finder

OS: Yosemite

I am very new on Mac, I was removing a software and cleaning up after it, I got to know after a week or so that I deleted all files and folders related to *Messages* app.

The files are still inside the trash but there is no **put back** option since *Finder* isn't running with root privilege.

I tried searching the app to download it and I don't know why it was no luck at all, I also tried to run *Finder* with root privilege but *DropBox* service keep crashing it after running in root so also no luck.

Any advice here please ?

Comment: Apple says to reinstall OS X, which apparently doesn’t remove your data. But perhaps someone can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Yeah I've read that but it's a real headache to do it, I trying to come up with a better solution and contacting them at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the locations for the data, so you can put everything back.

Messages.app `/Applications/`

chat.db, chat.db-shm, chat.db-wal `~/Library/Messages/`

Any attachments go in `~/Library/Messages/Attachments/`

### EDIT

Nearly forgot the Caches.

any Cache files go in `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Messages`

### EDIT 2

Found it!

the nib file and strings files belong in /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/??.lproj. do a search for one of the missing strings. there will only be one missing entry - I'm assuming en.lproj do the same for the nib file.

### EDIT 3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ94N.png <-- these are the files requested.

Comment: Those two I had a clue about them and restored them there, but I have files like *iMessageSignInViewController.strings* (33 files), one **.nib** file and 3 *Messages* folders, any idea where to go with those ?

Comment: Also put the cache files back, confused about the other files mentioned in my previous comment!

Comment: I don't use a Mac, but, if you're alright with losing your message history, clear those 3 folders completely, and start again. Give me a sec to fire up my mac

Comment: Not worried about the history, but for now there is no accounts when I launch the app and no options to link an account (it's like a broken app), so I'm guessing those *iMessageSignInViewController.strings* (33 files), and the .nib one are the key here, if you can search your mac on their path I can restore them to the same place and start Messages again.

Comment: FOUND IT! the nib file and the strings belong in /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/??.lproj. do a search for one of the missing strings. there will only be one missing entry - I'm assuming en.lproj do the same for the nib file. updated answer with this

Comment: iMessageSignInViewController.nib
Can you search for the location of this file exactly ?

Comment: that's the problem, there are multiple files with the same name

Comment: Not really, till now i'm getting the same errors, I can launch the app ofcourse but I can't add accounts, the configuration are stuck at default options... I tried pasting the files in all *.lproj directories but no luck yet, and Apple guys only had the solution of installing the system again, i'll keep this thread updated if I found a solution, maybe a hybrid one between what you suggested and my case.

Comment: I could just zip my version of messages.app for you...

Comment: Thanks man, won't work since the file itself isn't corrupted, the configuration files are missing from the right path, what you can help me with is install *AppCleaner* http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/ (a great free tool btw) and mark *Messages* for deletion then make a screen shot for the files with their paths :)